# I want the text to span the first clip path area only

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I want the text to span the first clip path area only, without spanning to the right clip path. I have tried several tweaks to no avail. The text should be on top of the clip path not in the bottom of the container.

```css
    .content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        color: black;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .text-container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .content::before,
    .content::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .content::before {
        background-color: #0A76E3;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 59% 0, 46% 100%, 0 100%);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .content::after {
        background-color: #ff4200;
        clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 0);
        right: 0;
        width: 20%;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="content h-screen">
    <div style="paddding-top: 22rem;" class='flex flex-row-2 pt-20 justify-start items-center px- mx-auto'>
        <div class="text-container flex flex-col justify-around w-g2/5">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-start gap-4 pb-4">
                <h2 class="text-6xl font-extrabold text-white">Who Are We</h2>
            </div>
            <h3 style="font-size: 1.5rem; background-clip: text; -webkit-background-clip: text; color: red; padding: 10px; display: inline-block; line-height: 1.5;" class="text-3xl space-y-4 z-50">We are an test payment test that allows users to securely make
                and receive payments through testtest phones over the testetses. From testetst to testetste, test test test, and
                everywhere else in test, we are a team of doers on a mission to improve the payment experience for everyone.</h3>
        </div>
        <img class="img w-2/6 absolute bottom-0 right-0 transform -translate-x-1/2" src="../media/images/computer.png" alt="image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any sample output image

Comment: yeah sure. uploading sample output image

Comment: Are  you saying that all the text should be over the blue area? And what do you want to happen on narrow viewports? Please show us a picture of what you are aiming for.

Comment: Would CSS shape-outside help?

Comment: I have updated with the image of the output i want to achieve

Comment: this should only happen in large screens

Comment: Any reason you haven’t tried shape-outside?

Comment: I'm trying shape-outshide but the text still span the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shape-outside fixed my issue. Here is the styling

```
    .content::before {
    background-color: #0A76E3;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 59% 0, 46% 100%, 0 100%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content::after {
    background-color: #ff4200;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 0);
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
}

.text-container {
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 59% 0, 46% 100%, 0 100%);
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 54%;
}
```